# Finding the sum of the convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{(1-i)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been given

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{i^n}{(1-i)^n}$$

and I have to find the sum. I ***don't*** have to show or prove this is convergent. I'm given that it's convergent, but I'm not exactly sure how to evaluate this. In the text and the course, we've used methods and learned how to show something converges. However, we have had no practice or experience finding the actual sum of a series. I did do some conjugation and simplifying to get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{i^n}{(1-i)^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}$$

Writing the first few terms of this series we get

$$1-\frac{1}{1-i}+\frac{1}{(1-i)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-i)^3}+\cdots$$

but I don't see how this is any help or useful. We have an alternating series with a complex denominator. However, the complex numbers cannot be ordered, and so I can't say $(1-i)^n < 1$. Perhaps this is just something from second semester calculus I've forgotten. That was four and a half years ago. Covid and a double major has really slowed things down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a geometric series:  for any $z \in \mathbb C$ such that $|z| < 1$, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}.$$  Therefore with the choice $z = i/(1-i)$, which indeed satisfies $|z| < 1$, the sum evaluates to $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{i}{1-i}} = \frac{3+i}{5}.$$

Comment: Embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: @user2661923 You evaluated $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(1-i)^n},$$ but that is not the original summand.  It should be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}$$ because $$\frac{i}{1-i} = \frac{-1}{1+i}.$$

Comment: Yes, my bad, I missed that.  I deleted my answer.